# What does "set up" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> *Trudging through the streets that led from Tottenham Court Road to Covent Garden I was aware of my invisibility again. When I got to
> Covent Garden all everyone could ask was ‘Where’s Bob?’ When I told
> people that he was ill they were all really concerned. ‘Is he going to
> be all right?’; ‘Is it serious?’; ‘Is he going to see a vet?’; ‘Is he
> OK on his own at home?’ It was then that an idea struck me. I had come
> across a vet nurse called Rosemary. Her boyfriend, Steve, worked at a
> comic-book shop near where we sometimes **set up**. Bob and I would pop in
> there every now and again and we had become friends. Rosemary had been
> in there with Steve one day and we’d struck up a conversation about
> Bob.*

Follows the full text above extracted from book ***"A Street Cat Named Bob"***.

I'd like to know the meaning of *"set up"* in the context of the phrase *"It was then that an idea struck me. I had come across a vet nurse called Rosemary. Her boyfriend, Steve, worked at a comic-book shop near where we sometimes **set up**."*.

Could you guys explain it?

Comment: I presume the first-person character speaking here, does something at several different temporary locations, such as a street vendor or busker. So "set up" would mean to put up an awning, table, music equipment, or whatever was necessary to do the thing at that location. It's not possible to tell without being familiar with the earlier parts of the book, so I am only writing this as a comment rather than as an answer.

Comment: What did you find in the dictionary? Or in any other efforts to find the answer?

Comment: @nebogipfel - the book was [written by a busker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Bowen_(author)#A_Street_Cat_Named_Bob). Bob the cat was, famously, his constant companion for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was said in a comment, the author of the book was a busker. That is, they would perform music or other skill on a sidewalk or in a park, and ask people to donate money. So, to "set up" means to prepare a location for their performance, perhaps setting up an amplifier, or setting out a basket for donations, and so on.